# Dialog state does not change after restarting (closing and opening again) in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have defined one button inside one StatelessWidget (This will have the bloc creation logic and injecting using bloc provider, ), on click of the button i am showing a dialog and passing the bloc instance to it, as shown in the code.

```
//EsignBloc is defined here in parent statelessWidget. Defined i.e. creating the bloc instance and passing through the BlocProvider. Removed the code for simplicity


//This listener will be called when Button defined inside statelessWidget will be clicked. this is responsible for showing the dialog.
void _onClickHere(
    BuildContext context,
  ) {
    final dialog = Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(AppConstants.borderRadius),
      ),
      elevation: 0.0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: _GetSignUsingOtpView(),
    );

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => BlocProvider<EsignBloc>(
        create: (_) => BlocProvider.of<EsignBloc>(context), // passing already created bloc to dialog
        child: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () => Future.value(false),
          child: dialog,
        ),
      ),
      barrierDismissible: false,
    );
  }
```

Pasting some code of _GetSignUsingOtpView()

```
class _GetSignUsingOtpView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<EsignBloc, EsignState>(builder: (context, state) {
      return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: AppColor.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
            AppConstants.borderRadius,
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () => _closeDialog(context),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, right: 8),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.cancel,
                        color: AppColor.primaryDark,
                        size: SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical * 2,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: [
                      PrimaryText(text: state.otp), // data does not change after closing and opeing dialog again 
                      PrimaryText(text: state.remainingTime), // data does not change after closing and opeing dialog again 
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
      );
    });
  }

  void _closeDialog(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
}
```

The problem that I am facing is whenever the dialog opens again after closing, it doesn't show the latest data from the bloc. The dialog just shows whatever previous data is in the bloc. Can someone point it out, where i am making the mistake?

Comment: Please add the code for your `EsignState` class, perhaps you missed to override the `props` for `Equatable`.

Comment: I am using freezed annotation to generate the code for EsignState

Answer (score 2):

The reason that your dialog is not showing new data is because you are creating a new instance of the bloc. Even though you say that you're not.

```dart
BlocProvider<EsignBloc>(
  create: (_) => BlocProvider.of<EsignBloc>(context), // passing already created bloc to dialog
  child: ...
```

> In some cases, BlocProvider can be used to provide an existing cubit to a new portion of the widget tree. This will be most commonly used when an existing cubit needs to be made available to a new route. In this case, BlocProvider will not automatically close the cubit since it did not create it.

To not create a new instance, you need to use `BlocProvider.value`. You can read more about it [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc#bloc-widgets)

```dart
BlocProvider.value(
  value: BlocProvider.of<EsignBloc>(context),
  child: ...,
);
```

Instead of creating a new instance, this will use the previous instance and provide it to the child widget and will NOT close the bloc when its done using it. This is handy for dialogs and navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the dialog has it own context that create a state that you cannot change directly because it is on the top of all layers, you have to rebuild entire dialog to make changes. But, I had similar problem and I solved it with the few steps, maybe it helps someone else:

1. You have to pass the same instance of the bloc from the parent widget where you have BlocProvider.

function:

```
void _someFunction(YourBloc yourBloc){...}
```

parent:

```
_someFunction(BlocProvider.of<YourBloc>(context));
```

2. Create a STATEFULL widget (not stateless) where you gonna make changes, and pass the same bloc in to it from the function now.
   You just pass it via constructor like:

> final YourBloc yourBloc;

3. In this widget use BlocListener and SetState method to update the UI in this widget.

> ```
>  BlocListener<YourBloc, YourState>(
>           bloc: widget.yourBloc,
>           listener: (context, state) {
>             setState(() {});
>           },
>           child: Text(widget.yourBloc.state.showExampleValue),
>         );
> ```